# Adding UIView on top of react native navigation

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation and trying to add a native view on the top of everything. I initialized the Swift class in AppDelegate and call swift func:

```
func showUp() {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    let rect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
    rect.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    window.addSubview(rect) }
```

The View seemed to be appeared while loading app and then disappears after app is 
loaded.

[image: Loading app screenshot...]

Thanks in advance)

Comment: Which version of 'react-native-navigation' do you use? v1 or v2?

Comment: I am using v1..

Comment: I tried to init swift class in different places like didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and applicationDidBecomeActive but behavior is same.